# Create image using raster photo layer with vector shapefile overlaid (landuse)

Tags: qgis, raster

I am a beginner with QGIS.

I have a raster aerial photo and wish to overlay a vector shapefile (I have already created) showing polygons of land use.

Can this be done in QGIS, or do I need to use photoshop?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, I guess if you want to do this in QGIS you should read some basics...  like [getting started](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that your vector layer is in the right projection and digitised correctly, then your raster must be georeferenced. In QGIS you will need to use the Georeferencer-plugin along with       a map-service open (like Google Satellite) within QGIS map canvas. Now you go read the rest.